# Python-Kivy: SoundLoader.load doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, runtime-error, kivy

Why can't I load sounds with Kivy, when I'm following the instructions on the Kivy website precisely? Any help is greatly appreciated!

The following example is from https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.audio.html:

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

sound = SoundLoader.load('mytest.wav')
if sound:
    print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
    print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
    sound.play()
```

I've copied and pasted this example into a blank Python file, and ran the code. I've made sure to use a valid wav file for 'mytest.wav', and have placed the wav file in the same directory as the Python file.

I get the following error message:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 /Users/MyUsername/PycharmProjects/MyProject/sound_test.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/MyUsername/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-10-24_4.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1.dev0, git-Unknown, 20170911
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
[INFO   ] [AudioGstplayer] Using Gstreamer 1.12.2.0
[INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_gstplayer, audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer, audio_avplayer ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/MyUsername/PycharmProjects/MyProject/sound_test.py", line 3, in <module>
     sound = SoundLoader.load("mytest.wav")
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/audio/__init__.py", line 86, in load
     return classobj(source=filename)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/audio/audio_gstplayer.py", line 45, in __init__
     super(SoundGstplayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 262, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 478, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 516, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 571, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1120, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/audio/__init__.py", line 174, in on_source
     self.load()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/audio/audio_gstplayer.py", line 62, in load
     self.player.load()
   File "kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx", line 233, in kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayer.load
 kivy.lib.gstplayer._gstplayer.GstPlayerException: Unable to create a playbin

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've also tried getting rid of the code below line 3, but that doesn't affect the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows every extensions of music files work since kivy came with GStreamer that handle all the formats but On some other platform only the .ogg works, convert your file to the ogg format then retry.

If it does not work, I think there is a problem with your kivy installation please try to re-install kivy following those steps:

1.Install the requirements using homebrew:

```
$ brew install sdl2 sdl2_image sdl2_ttf sdl2_mixer gstreamer
```

2.Install cython 0.23 and kivy using pip:

```
 $ pip install -I Cython==0.23
 $ USE_OSX_FRAMEWORKS=0 pip install kivy
```

I really hope this works since I don't have mac os to test it

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm actually using Mac OS X. Should I still convert the file to ogg? I can play wav files just fine on my Mac. The problem seems to be loading the file with Kivy, rather than playing the file. Also, when I used Pygame (before switching to Kivy) the same file loaded and played without any issues.

Comment: Yes I don't know much about Mac OS X but I think you should

Comment: You don't have to convert the wav file. I have no problem playing wav files on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Dear @ikolim If he want to package his application to android or ios after, this is the best solution

Comment: I have converted the file to ogg and retried. Unfortunately I get the same error message...

Comment: Sorry I apologize for that, I updated my answer please try to follow those steps @Auggie

Comment: Thank you, @SPSP! I tried those steps. It turns out my computer is too old to upgrade to the latest version of gstreamer. I'm not sure if that's what's causing the issue, but maybe it's time for me to buy a new computer. If a new computer fixes the issue, I will gladly accept your answer. :)

Comment: @SPSP - I finally got a new computer, and the sound issue with kivy has been resolved, so I'm happy to accept your answer. Sorry for the delay, and thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who comes across this issue on OS X. The problem for me was the kivy.lib.gstreamer directory. After I removed this directory SoundLoader worked fine.

Go to terminal and navigate to where Kivy is installed. On my machine it was in usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lib

Once you are in /lib type:

```
rm -R gstreamer
```